# Using regex (or otherwise) to split logic statement string into parts and structure in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to split a series of strings that are bracketed combinations of logical tests, and I want to split them into their constituate parts. For example if I have the string:

```
string logicalExpression = "((integerValue != 100) AND (stringValue == 'test' OR anotherInteger == 90) AND (anotherString == 'test2' OR anotherString == 'test3'))";
```

I would want to end up with the string variables that would be defined as:

```
string expressionA = "integerValue != 100";
string expressionB = "stringValue == 'test'";
string expressionC = "anotherInteger == 90";
string expressionD = "anotherString == 'test2'";
string expressionE = "anotherString == 'test3'";

string expressionStructure = "((A) AND (B OR C) AND (D OR E))";
```

There could be any number of logical tests, and the combination of ANDs and ORs and brackets could be anything that forms a valid logical test.

I figure once I've got the variables expressionA to expresssionE then getting expressionStructure is simple enough with the replace function. And I figure I can probably get expressionA to expressionE out using regex - but unfortunately I suck at regex. Anyone got any ideas how to do this - using regex or otherwise?

Comment: You could have a look at the Antlr project. It let's you define grammars and will parse the string into a syntax tree and tokens.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will produces the result for expression A - E,

```
string logicalExpression = "((integerValue != 100) AND(stringValue == 'test' OR anotherInteger == 90) AND(anotherString == 'test2' OR anotherString == 'test3'))";



string[] result = Regex.Matches(logicalExpression, @"(?<=\().+?(?=\))", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
                               .Cast<Match>()
                               .Select(match => match.Groups[0].Value)
                               .ToArray();

string expressionA = result[0].Substring(1);
string expressionB = result[1].Substring(0, result[1].IndexOf("OR"));
string expressionC = Regex.Match(result[1], @"OR\b(.*)\b").Value;
string expressionD = result[2].Substring(0, result[2].IndexOf("OR"));
string expressionE = Regex.Match(result[2], @"OR\b(.*)\b").Value;
```